# Pandas Remove Whitespace or Indent

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame which consists of raw data read from a `.txt` file using:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("Chat.txt", sep = "delimiter",skip_blank_lines = True, header = None, engine='python')
```

[image]

From the above screenshot the DataFrame appears to have some sort of indent or white spaces which make DataFrame operations frustrating. However when I copy and paste the DataFrame on StackOverflow it yields this (Possibly SO applies a default operation on it):

```py
Data
0   [08/10/18, 5:21:25 PM] Message
1   [08/10/18, 5:21:25 PM] Message
2   [08/10/18, 5:21:57 PM] Message
3   [08/10/18, 5:22:22 PM] Message
4   [08/10/18, 5:22:36 PM] Message
```

I've tried using

```py
df['Data'] = df['Data'].str.strip()
```

which results in no effect.

Please Advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? IIUC, you are trying to left-align the column such that no whitespaces are left while displaying the data frame.

**If you are using `df.column.str.strip()` that would remove all the unnecessary spaces. What you are seeing is the alignment during displaying the pandas dataframe. They are not actual spaces infront of the column values.**

You can use `dataframe.style` methods to render the dataframe in required formats. NOTE: this is only a change during rendering/printing the data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['foo', 'bar', 'apple', 'banana', 'kiwi'],
                 'number': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})
```

[image]

Comment: Does `df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})` remove white spaces if they exist?

Comment: White spaces you mean the initial spaces infront of each value in a column? can you test the method that I have shown?

Comment: Yeah the initial; spaces, but it doesn't have a permanent effect on the df

Comment: Like i mentioned. if you are using `str.strip()` it will ensure you are removing all the spaces already.

Comment: Are you resetting the column after using `strip`?? can you print only `df['data']` before and after `df['Data'] = df['Data'].str.strip()`

Comment: Yeah I was performing operations on it

Comment: can you print the pre and post state of he column? like i ask above? Just copy paste to stack overflow'

Comment: The pre state of the column on pandas is on the screenshot and the  pre state of the column on SO is already pasted above. However since I'm dealing with a large data set using your method prints all the data to the console causing Jupyter to crash.

Comment: You can just do it for `sample_df = df.head()` and test your codes on that...  If the pre-state of the column is as you have pasted on SO. then you dont have any whitespaces. The screenshot is that of `display(df)` while the copy paste is that of `print(df)`. The print that you are doing shows the data is as it should be. The display is left aligning text column just to display it. It doesnt contain any white spaces. what make you think it does?

Comment: Do mark the answer if it helped you and do upvote it if it’s well written to your liking. This encourages me to help solve your future questions :)